# Word Macro: Move Cursor Down a Row

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, macros, vba

I have a macro which I've been using to merge two cells together in a word table, but what I want to do is to get the cursor to move down by one cell, so that I can repeatedly press the shortcut key to repeat the command over and over.

The macro code that I have (shamelessy copied and pasted from a web page), is as follows:

```
Sub MergeWithCellToRight()
'
' MergeWithCellToRight Macro
'
'
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oCell As Cell
Set oCell = Selection.Cells(1)
If oCell.ColumnIndex = Selection.Rows(1).Cells.Count Then
MsgBox "There is no cell to the right?", vbCritical, "Error"
Exit Sub
End If
Set oRng = oCell.Range
oRng.MoveEnd wdCell, 1
oRng.Cells.Merge
Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
End Sub
```

I've attempted to add the following line just before the 'End Sub' statement

```
Selection.MoveDown wdCell, 1
```

but this generates the error, `Run-time error '4120' Bad Parameter` whenever I execute the macro.

Can anyone tell me how to correct this or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea if that could help, but I have the following:

```
Sub Merges2Cols()
Dim nbLines As Integer
    nbLines = 10     'you'd have to count the number of lines you want to merge
    For i = 1 To nbLines
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.Cells.Merge
        Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing wrong, but I just ran across the exact same problem.  I found that this works for moving the cursor down one row.

```
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCell, Count:=Selection.Tables(1).Columns.Count
```

And if you want to move up one row:

```
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCell, Count:=Selection.Tables(1).Columns.Count
```

This will work for tables where each row has the same number of columns. Not sure how it works if some rows have merged columns.